# Merge 2 dataframe an add NaN if no hit

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 dataframes:

```
qseqid  sseqid  pident  length  mismatch
seq1    seq24   78       789     45
seq2    seq12   73       790     44
seq3    seq34   12       77      42
seq4    seq90   70       790     41
```

and another one such:

```
seq2_id       tax_inf
seq3          Virus
seq1          Eucaryote
```

and I would to merge these two df such as:

```
qseqid  sseqid  pident  length  mismatch tax_inf
seq1    seq24   78       789     45       Eucaryote
seq2    seq12   73       790     44       NaN
seq3    seq34   12       77      42       Virus
seq4    seq90   70       790     41       NaN
```

Comment: it does make sense to read [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)... `df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=..., right_on=...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need,

```
 pd.merge(df1,df2.rename(columns={'seq2_id':'qseqid'}),on='qseqid',how='outer')
```